# Migration of Onclick javascript custom links from salesforce classic to lightning

Tags: javascript

I have a custom `OnClick` JavaScript link that is used for Quote functionality.  The `OnClick` JavaScript will not work with Lightning.

How should I migrate it to lightning
on click of the link a `popout` is generated which contains a PDF.
the `javascript` code is below

```
var pdfOverlay = QuotePDFPreview.quotePDFObjs['quotePDFOverlay']; 
pdfOverlay.summlid = '{!$Setup.QuoteLinks__c.Institution_Quote_Detail_Template_ID__c}';pdfOverlay.setSavable(true); 


pdfOverlay.dialog.buttonContents = 
"<input value=Save class=btn onclick=QuotePDFPreview.getQuotePDFObject(&apos;quotePDFOverlay&apos;).savePDF(&apos;0&apos;,&apos;0&apos;); type='button' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input value=Email class=btn onclick=QuotePDFPreview.getQuotePDFObject(&apos;quotePDFOverlay&apos;).savePDF(&apos;1&apos;); type='button' />"; 


pdfOverlay.setContents('/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id={!Quote.Id}','/quote/quoteTemplateHeaderData.apexp?id={!Quote.Id}'); 
pdfOverlay.display();
```

Comment: You cant migrate the button, you need to create a lightning component with the same functionality as your button

Comment: @Torsen I am very new to this. can you please help ?

Comment: @Torsen I know that it can't migrate but how can I achieve the above mentioned functionality in lightning ? Do u really think I need to create a lighting component?

Comment: @Apoorv Did you get this working in Lightning?

Comment: no. I posted this on behalf of one of my friends